# msbuild not collecting static web assets from dependencies in restricted environment

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor webassembly project which requires some web assets from its dependencies (most of such projects require some).

When I build the project on my machine, everything works fine.

However, when I try to run the very same build in a containerized environment, the application still builds without any errors or warnings, but static web assets are not included in the publishable output.

Withing the containerized environment I have exactly the same toolchain and deps installed (dotnet core 6.0.102). Env vars are different (restricted subset).

I have checked the usual culprits (strace, etc). I can see the relevant asset files and associated prop files being read by msbuild successfully. Yet, when I inspect "Initial items" section in the msbuild log, `StaticWebAsset` subsection is missing outright, even if I invoke the `ResolveStaticWebAssetsConfiguration` target directly.

Yet, on my normal workstation everything "just works".

Does somebody know what can cause msbuild to ignore all the static web asset property files post successful reading of those (as confirmed by strace)?

Comment: I think you need to do a "dotnet publish" to get all the assets

Comment: "Initial Items" get populated pretty early on in the build cycle, and any invoked target can only use whatever is already in that tree. However, I managed to find out the root cause of the above issue: it was caused by `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` variable, or rather the crazy way msbuild is using it.